# Rails model validations not running on custom `create` action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called `Post` which store two types of posts: Questions and Answers:

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer       "post_type_id",  # 1 for Question, 2 for Answers
    t.integer       "parent_id"      # contains post_id of question if it's an answer
    t.text          "body", :null => false
end
```

The `create` action in the `posts_controller` is used to create Questions.

So I created a second create action in the routes like this to handle creation of Answers from the answer form:

```
resources :posts do
    post 'answer' => "posts#create_answer", as: :answer
end
```

The problem is that even though the `body` field is required, rails doesn't run those validations for my custom `create_answer` controller action.

I am able to post an answer with a blank `body`. The validations do work as usual for the normal `create` action (which is used to create posts with type Questions).

**How can I get railed to run model validations for a custom controller action that handles object creation?**

PS. There is different business logic for creation of posts with type question or answer... that is why I need separate create actions for both.

**Update:**

Here is the Post model:

```
class Post < MyModel
    strip_attributes

    # relationships
    belongs_to :question, :class_name => 'Post', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
    has_many   :answers,    :class_name => 'Post', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'

    # validations
    validates :post_type_id,        :presence => true,
                                    :numericality => true

    validates :parent_id,           :numericality => true,
                                    :allow_nil => true

    validates :user_id,             :presence => true,
                                    :numericality => true

    validates :body,                :presence => true
end
```

Here is the `create_answer` action:

```
def create_answer
    if @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
        @answer = current_user.posts.new(
            :post_type_id => 2,
            :parent_id => @post.id,
            :body => post_params[:body])

        if @answer.save
            flash[:notice] = "Answer posted"
            redirect_to @post
        else
            logger.fatal "Answer saving failed"
            flash[:error] = "Something went wrong while posting your answer. We're looking into it."
            redirect_to :back
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You need to show us the actual code in question, the validation itself, and the `create_answer` method.

Comment: can you post the model code for `answer` and controller code for `create_answer` ?

Comment: @JustinWood Added both code to question.

Comment: I think you are bringing trouble to yourself by abusing self referential association.

Comment: @BillyChan How would you recommend changing this? By creating two separate models?

Comment: That's sure thing if I do it. Question and Answer. They are very simple things. Why making it complicated?

Comment: @BillyChan There are other post types as well, so thought I'd avoid creating all those separate models. I guess separating them is probably best.

Comment: @BillyChan This is the stackexchange schema btw. They have a single Post table as well.

Comment: Then how about you have a Question and Answer model inherited from Post. They have a type attribute which is "question" or "answer" or others. This is how OOP polymorphic works. This should help to make things simple.

Comment: @BillyChan I see. I had never done that before -- didn't know that a model can be created without an underlying table for it.

Comment: @BillyChan I see a polymorphic association would work for something like comments, but how would one structure it for something like this? (Questions and Answers > which are both Posts).

Comment: I'm not sure how to use existing Rails method on that. But Polymophic is just a design pattern and it's easy to write it by yourself. Say in Question, add an `before_create` callback to set its type as `question`.

Comment: What makes you think that the validations aren't running?

Comment: @NickUrban I'm able to post with the field being blank (even though the model validation prevents it).

Comment: What do you mean "able to post"? Do you mean that you're seeing the "Answer posted" message?

Comment: Able to post as in if I submit the form blank through the browser, the record gets created in the db (with the body as an empty string).